# What kinds of companies/businesses do Suzuka's and Arisa's parents own?

Tags: nanoha

In *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha*, Arisa and Suzuka are both heiresses.

From what I can read from the wikia, [Suzuka's](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Suzuka_Tsukimura) family is from Triangle Heart 3 as her older sister Shinobu is one of the heroines; however, Suzuka herself doesn't exist.

For [Arisa](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Arisa_Bunnings), it says her parents are company owners and she was adapted from Arisa Lowell; however, Triangle Heart 3 isn't patched in English, nor can I find a wiki for it explaining how much of Arisa Lowell was adapted to Arisa Bunnings.

So I am looking for information regarding the companies/businesses Suzuka's and Arisa's parents own which makes them so rich.